# How to find file/device given the resource ID on Linux?

Tags: linux, file-descriptors

On a gentoo Linux system I am printing the value of a file descriptor from within a PHP script yielding the following output:

```
Resource id #1234
```

How to find the corresponding file/device given this resource id?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number is indeed the Unix file descriptor, you can find out using

```
ls -l /proc/$PID/fd/1234
```

where instead of `$PID` you insert the PID of the PHP process (which you can get e.g. using `ps`). For example, in an interactive bash I get with

```
ls -l /proc/$$/fd/0
```

(`$$` is the current shell's PID in bash) the output

```
lrwx------ 1 ******** ******** 64 Okt 16 14:24 /proc/21239/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/4
```

telling me that the file descriptor `0` (which is stdin) refers to the file `/dev/pts/4` (which is the pseudo-terminal device the shell is running on).

Comment: Your suggestion sounds sane, but does not work for my case. When I look into the process' fd folder I do not see anything that resembles the resource-id number. Probable the php resource-id does not resemble the Unix file descriptor.

Comment: @Alex: If it is a PHP specific number, then your question is actually a PHP question, and probably better asked on Stack Overflow, since I'd expect more PHP experts there.